# Why 422 (Unprocessable Entity) showing?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using a `delete` method in angular js,

**Controller** :

```
$scope.delete = function(object) {
     $scope.deleteobject = {"id":object.id}
     authService.deletedetails($scope.deleteobject).success(function(data, status) {
         console.log("succesfully deleted");
     }).error(function(data, status) {
         console.log("data:",data);
         console.log("status",status);
     });
}
```

**Service** is

```
service.deletedetails = function(user) {
  return $http.delete('/api/delete', user);

}
```

everything is correct, but still showing the `error`, but `delete` work in the `rest api` app.

Facing Error :-

`DELETE localhost:8100/api/delete 422 (Unprocessable Entity) Entryview.js:44 data: Object {Message: "Not Deleted"} Entryview.js:45 status 422 Entryview.js:47 config Object {method: "DELETE", transformRequest: Array[1], transformResponse: Array[1], id: 23, url: "/api/delete"…} –`

Comment: Actually Code should Delete as per its functionality . can you update the Full error ? & check the headers while sending via restApi or Postman  & from the Code snippet that may give you some clue ..

Comment: iDELETE http://localhost:8100/api/delete 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
Entryview.js:44 data: Object {Message: "Not Deleted"}
Entryview.js:45 status 422
Entryview.js:47 config Object {method: "DELETE", transformRequest: Array[1], transformResponse: Array[1], id: 23, url: "/api/delete"…}

Comment: @Vispriya check this stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006502/angular-http-delete-returns-error-422-unprocessable-entity